# CLS optimization for page with many PHP conditions

Tags: php, google-pagespeed

I have a php page with many PHP conditions. Depending on the ID of the page, different content is shown:

```
<?php if( is_page( 'p-1' )  ) { ?>
 <div class="div-a">
    <div class="div-b">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if( is_page( 'p-2' )  ) { ?>
 <div class="div-a">
    <div class="div-b">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if( is_page( 'p-3' )  ) { ?>
 <div class="div-a">
    <div class="div-b">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that the conditions are written for more than 70 pages, and after measuring the PageSpeed Insights metrics, the report gives me that my CLS indicator is too high.

The funny thing is that the content that is shown on the desired page is only one and consists of only a few divs. The rest of the content related to other pages, of course, is not shown. There are no images in the content, places for banners, etc. - just a couple of divs and a paragraph inside. If all other `php if` conditions are removed, the problem disappears and the metrics are fine. I've already racked my brains on how to fix this problem without removing the conditions and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Apart from the fairly obvious recommendation to split the 70 conditions into 70 separate templates and then conditionally include just the one you want, I'd debug further by generating the page for `p-1` with all the conditions in place, saving a copy of it, temporarily removing all the other conditions, and generating the same page again. Then you can diff the two copies and see what the actual change is.

Comment: Your report should have a spot that you can click on to see the specific details about the CLS

Comment: Also, the way you have it structured, you are making 70 calls to `is_page()` every time because you aren't using an `elseif`. You can see a mock demo of what I mean here: https://3v4l.org/3YmX1. Even if the first one is true, the other 69 will still always call that function the way it is currently written.

Comment: I know that `is_page()` is a WordPress function, but I don't know if this is a WordPress site or not. If it is, having code depend on specific pages can be very fragile and, as you have seen with 70 pages, doesn't scale well. Maybe consider adding a field to the page that outputs the specific text instead? You could register a custom template, too, so that you could "upgrade" your code into the new pattern while retaining BC until it can be migrated. If this isn't WordPress, the same general logic still applies, but depends on your system obviously.